# Sys.timeDate takes local time zone if converted to dataframe ? Probably a bug?

Tags: r, datetime, timestamp

Why does the SYs.timeDate considers local time if converted to dataframe ?

```
timeDate::Sys.timeDate(FinCenter = "America/Mexico_City")
America/Mexico_City
[1] [2019-11-28 03:31:07]

(timestamp = timeDate::Sys.timeDate(FinCenter = "America/Mexico_City")) %>%
+           as.data.frame()
  America/Mexico_City:.
1   2019-11-28 09:31:30
```